# error ::: bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: sql

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, tbl.* 
     FROM
         (SELECT * 
          FROM notice
            <include refid="search" />
          ORDER BY notice_NO DESC) tbl
    )
<![CDATA[
WHERE rn > (#{pageNum}-1) * #{cpp}
  AND rn <= #{pageNum} * #{cpp}
]]>
```

But when I run it, I get an error

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 2):

As the message says you need to give an alias to every derived table, and your 2nd SELECT (from top) does not have one:

```
SELECT * FROM
        (
        SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, tbl.* FROM
            (
            SELECT * FROM notice
            <include refid="search" />
            ORDER BY notice_NO DESC
            ) tbl
        ) tbl2 --<<<< Add this
    <![CDATA[
    WHERE rn > (#{pageNum}-1) * #{cpp}
    AND rn <= #{pageNum} * #{cpp}
    ]]>
```